# How to call Object Methods while object is in a thread? Ruby (not rails)

Tags: ruby, multithreading, object

If I put an object inside a thread, how do I call methods on that object. Example of what I want to do below & my current error.

> undefined method `_method_name' for ["var", #Thread:0x00007f9b181edec0@b.rb:183

```
threads = {}

freq.each do |var|
  threads[var] = Thread.new {object.new.method}
end

while true
  threads.each do |thr|
    thr.method_inside_the_object
  end
end
```

Comment: _"Example of what I want to do [...]"_ – this seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly generate the error message you posted. Please, make sure that post a [mcve] that accurately represents your actual problem.

Comment: Also, what does it mean to "put an object inside a thread"? A thread contains code, not objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this:

```
Thread.new { ... }
```

The `{ ... }` is a *[block](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html)* that will be executed by the new thread.  If you want the thread to do something interesting,
then you have to provide code (the `...`) to do the interesting thing.

---

Typically, the original thread goes on to do something else *[concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing)* with the new thread:

```
Thread.new { ... }
do_something_else()
```

Doing things concurrently (maybe even, *[in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)*) is the whole point of multi-threading after all.

---

Threads communicate by accessing shared objects... but it doesn't make any sense for one thread to look at a shared object until it knows the the the other thread has finished updating it.  The simplest way is to `join()` the other thread.

```
t = Thread.new { ... }
do_something_else()
t.join()   # this simply waits until the thread has finished.
```

Now about those shared objects.  It's especially easy in Ruby.

```
shared_object = Hash.new()
t = Thread.new {
    shared_object["a"] = ...
    shared_object["b"] = ...
    ...
}
do_something_else()
t.join()
# after the join() call returns, it's safe to look in shared_object
# to see what the other thread left for us.
do_something_with(shared_object["a"])
...
```

---

There's a whole other issue that arises if you need the main thread to access `shared_object` concurrently with the new thread (i.e., *before* it calls `t.join()`).  Google for "race condition", or "locking", or "mutual exclusion", or "[mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html)" for more information about why that's tricky, and how to do it safely.